# Asp.Net Core 3.1 Publish via FTP

Tags: asp.net-core, publish, web-hosting

Im trying publish my first asp.net core 3.1 project via ftp . Im taking HTTP Error 500.35 - ANCM Multiple In-Process Applications in same Process . Thanx all

Comment: `HTTP Error 500.35 - ANCM Multiple In-Process Applications in same Process` You can try to check if each ASP.NET Core app on IIS gets separate Application Pool.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are having issues after you've uploaded your project over FTP on IIS. 
Check the settings of your website in IIS. This is definitely not an FTP issue.
You can enable logging in web.config file and get more information regarding what is stopping your app from running on the server...

And I have a few questions to be able to analyze more precise your problem.
Did you run this application before on this server without problems, or this is the first time you are trying to deploy on this server?

If the app had never run on this server, does this server have all requisites to operate .net core?

If no to the previous question. Maybe you can go with self contained deployment... strategy of your app...

Well in general there is a lot ways this could go wrong. Let us know more information after you enable debugging and maybe you could publish here the log file.

Hope it helps.

Comment: " Did you run this application before on this server without problems, or this is the first time you are trying to deploy on this server?" No

Comment: No to which part of the two-in-one question? haha

Answer (score 0):

thanx for answer and help . ım sorry for latency . 
ı solved my problem editing project file and adding these lines

```
<PropertyGroup>
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
<AspNetCoreHostingModel>OutOfProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
<AspNetCoreModuleName>AspNetCoreModule</AspNetCoreModuleName>
<UserSecretsId>******************</UserSecretsId>
```